# How do I add the ability to tag a person in a chat?

Tags: flutter, chat

I am doing just a chat on Firebase. But I want to add the ability to mark a person in the chat, and then send a notification to him by push notification.
How can this be done with flutter?
This should be implemented like any chat application, like: @Mike, How are you?

Comment: Your question leaves no possible way for someone to help you, other than write the whole feature for you. Try implementing the feature yourself, and ask a question when you have a specific problem.

Comment: @BenediktJSchlegel I was thinking of implementing a similar feature for my app, so it was a bit easy for me, and yes I had to implement the whole feature ;D

Answer (score 0):

You will need to accomplish it using the following steps. Haven't implemented it yet, but I planned do to something similar for my app.

Create a future that returns userId taking username as a parameter.

```
Future<String> getUserFromUsername(String word) async {

    final result = await FirebaseFirestore.instance
        .collection('users')
        .where('username', isEqualTo: word)
        .limit(1)
        .get();

    return result.docs.map((doc) => doc.data()['userID'].toString()).first;
  }
```

Use RichText to use separate styles for separate words.

```
RichText(
        text: TextSpan(
        children: userData.wildestGoal.split(' ').map((word) {
                  
           if (word.startsWith('@')) {

                return TextSpan(
                            text: '$word ',
                            style: TextStyle(
                                      color: Theme.of(context).primaryColor,
                                      fontSize: 16.0
                                            ),
                            recognizer: TapGestureRecognizer()
                                    ..onTap = () async {
                                      
                                    final String userId =
                                          await FireStoreService(
                                                  userId: FirebaseAuth
                                                      .instance.currentUser.uid)
                                              .getUserFromUsername(word
                                                  .split('@')[1]
                                                  .toString());
                                      Navigator.push(
                                          context,
                                          MaterialPageRoute(
                                              builder: (context) =>
                                                  ProvidersForUserProfile(
                                                    userId: userId,
                                                  )
                                          )
                                       );
                                    }
                                 );
                         }
                        return TextSpan(
                            text: '$word ',
                            style: const TextStyle(fontSize: 16.0));
                      }).toList()),
                    )
```